# freeimage convert png 24bit to 1bit black/white = grey/white?

Tags: grayscale, freeimage, 24-bit

I am using Freeimage.sf.net to load an png24bit and want to save it as black/white png.
using

`FIBITMAP bib = Freeimage.Load("<24bit_png>");`

`FIBITMAP conv = FreeImage.ConvertColorDepth(bib, FREE_IMAGE_COLOR_DEPTH. FICD_01_BPP_THRESHOLD, (byte) 128);`

`FreeImage.Unload(bin); bib.SetNull();`

`FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_PNG, conv, "<out_png>", FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.PNG_Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);`

`FreeImage.Unload(conv); conv.SetNull();`

but the  is not black/white, as it is #0b120c / white?
why does the threshold not create a bw-palette?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
FIBITMAP conv = FreeImage.ConvertColorDepth( bib,
                   FREE_IMAGE_COLOR_DEPTH.FICD_01_BPP_THRESHOLD, (byte) 128 );
```

builds a palette for the most used colors.

Replacing it with

```
FIBITMAP bw = FreeImage.Threshold( biRef, threshold_BW );
```

will create a truly black-and-white image.